# JQuery / Ajax - call function on complete of multiple JSON / GET requests

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I'm making multiple JSON GETs until a condition is met. The problem with the code below is that the function `tuneTileLoadedFunction()` is called before the condition is met (before the final GET request). I only want to call that function when the final load has completed.

How can I do this? Is it something to do with http://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/ ? I've had a look at this but can't make sense of it in relation to what I've already done.

When I place `tuneTileLoadedFunction()` in place of //whatever it doesn't call the function (I guess because the data hasn't loaded yet).

Thanks :)

```
checkIfTuneTileLoaded();  
function checkIfTuneTileLoaded() {

  var tuneTileLoaded = $("a[href*='" + location.pathname + "']").length;
  alert(tuneTileLoaded);

    if (tuneTileLoaded == 1) {

        //whatever

    }  else  {

        alert('tuneTileNotPresent');
        tumblrPostsRetrieved += 20;

        $.ajax({ 
        type: 'GET', 
        url: 'http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/onrepeatthisweek.tumblr.com/posts?api_key=cCaCiEE6kd5pInej2YFU0xdC4msLOE3R3IhYXcR1W6Irza8sJq&tag=overandoverandoverandover&offset=' + tumblrPostsRetrieved, 
        data: { get_param: 'value' }, 
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function (data) {
                    for (i = 0; i <= 19; i++) {
                    $('#recent-posts').append('<li><a href="' + data.response.posts[i].post_url +'"> ' + data.response.posts[i].title + '</li>');
                    }
                    maxScrollLeft = document.getElementById("tunesID").scrollWidth - document.getElementById("tunesID").clientWidth;
                    checkIfTuneTileLoaded();
                    tuneTileLoadedFunction();
                    alert('success');
                 }
        });
    }
}
```

UPDATE / RESOLVED:

I didn't solve the problem I was trying to solve (listening for the end of a recursive function with an Ajax request in it). The solution for me was instead of waiting for every request to complete, I checked each item as they were rendered for what I was looking for:

```
for (i = 0; i <= 19; i++) {
        $('#recent-posts').append('<li><a href="' + data.response.posts[i].post_url +'"> ' + data.response.posts[i].title + '</li>');
        if (data.response.posts[i].post_url == window.location) {
            tuneTileLoaded = 1;
            tuneTileLoadedFunction();
        }
        }
```

Comment: `tuneTileLoadedFunction();` seems to be called after the 2nd GET request, I thought it would have been after the 1st. Crucially, it is before the third and final. You can see this in action here: http://onrepeatthisweek.tumblr.com/post/38909622396/006-bart-b-more-brap

Comment: well, you definitely don't want to call it where it is. You instead want checkIfTuneLoaded to have a callback that gets executed when it's ajax calls are complete so you can execute tuneTileLoadedFunction at that point.

Comment: Yeah I understand your logic I just don't have the knowledge to implement it. I don't know how to listen for all GET requests being completed.

Comment: you don't need to listen for them all, only the last one since you're only sending 1 at a time.

Comment: Look at it this way. This is a recursive function. When it stops recursing, you know that it is done.

Comment: `function checkIfTuneTileLoaded(callback) {
//other code
tuneTileLoadedFunction();
}`

Comment: I've just tried that but again it calls every time I make the ajax request rather than when it's stopped recursing.

Comment: put `tuneTileLoadedFunction();` here: `//whatever` because that's where you're sure that all of the ajax requests are done (because that's where it stops recursing)

Comment: Yeah I noted in my original question that I'd tried that but now that you mention it again, it's made me realise that it's not making the 3rd ajax request when it should be meaning that `tuneTileLoaded` could never be 1

Comment: I only see 1 ajax request. don't count additional trips through the function as additional ajax requests, look at each iteration as it's own process. Each time you loop, you're getting data and then starting over. What sets tuneTileLoaded to 1? if it is tuneTileLoadedFunction, then you have no choice but to run it before `checkIfTuneTileLoaded();`, and then not execute `checkIfTuneTileLoaded();` until after `tuneTileLoadedFunction` is complete.

Comment: Each time we pass through the function we request different data as there's a variable ( `tumblrPostsRetrieved` ) that is incremented and appended to the URL request. Then every time we've received the data and rendered it I want to check the page to see if it includes a certain URL. If it does include that certain URL, tuneTileLoaded will equal 1.

Comment: Edited the comment above. But as far as I can tell, it's only recursing once and not infinitely.

Comment: Many thanks for your help Kevin B. I didn't manage to figure how to do what I was originally intending to but I did work out a workaround. You can see this workaround as I've updated the original post above.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to move the tuneTileLoadedFunction() out of the success call or wrap it in a conditional, or else it will be executed after each GET request.

Comment: Yeah I know what you're saying but I don't know how to do it. I don't how how to listen for all GET requests being complete.

Comment: It will call that done function only when the condition is met inside that xyz function. Done callback gets triggered only when deferred object is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You can user promises for such kind of problem. Use $.Deferred(). Please find documentation [here](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/). You can do something like this:

```
function xyz() {
   var dfd = $.Deferred();

   for ( i = 0 ; i < =19 ; i++ ) {
      //do something

      if( condition ) {
        dfd.resolve();
      }

   return dfd.promise();

}

xyz.done( tuneTileLoadFunction );
```

Hope that makes sense to you.

Comment: Yeah would this work for at the end of a recursive function or would it call the done function everytime?